# "GET /static/my_style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1660

Tags: python, django, static, syntax-error, django-staticfiles

Im getting this error "GET /static/my_style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1660 in my terminal whenever I update my page I build. I think it's my code in my settings.py that is wrong and with the static files also.

Tried different thing but still not working

My static code right now

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
]
```

This type of error

[06/Nov/2019 19:54:58] "GET /static/my_style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1660

Comment: You gave too little information. Does this happen in debug mode? Where is the file on disk? How do you link the file in your template? Using the static tag?

Comment: PROB fixed!                                                                                                        Just fixed the problem and the problem was that my file was in the wrong directory. So when having this type of prob                                                            1) See if the files are in the correct place.                                                                        2) Check the spelling error specially between '' '' .

Answer (score 0):

Change your main Django apps sittings below this code.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static")
```

This above code is enough to remove your errors. But you also can use this below code too.

Put this code on your polls Apps urls.py (below urlpatterns = []). For example,U have ur code like this

```
urlpatterns = [ .....
]
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and then run this command

> python manage.py collectstatic

Answer (score 0):

```
    First open setting.py
     import os
    after create this :
        STATICFILE_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    ]
    remember one thing your static folder should be present in Base directory for this path when you create this only you have to run css in html as usual. 
for eg: i want to have blue colur on background so i simply create [class="body"] in html and on style.css:
    .body{
    background-color: blue;
    }
```